# I am trying to print multiple pages with fop

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to addd multiple pages with this code. The content of each page works individiually. I looked for an example on how to add multiple pages but everyone I came has not worked for me. Am I making some general error here? It would be really helpful if some could add the basic structure I would need to use for to pages.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<fo:root
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions"    
    font-family="Freesans">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="standard"
                               page-height="15.2cm"
                               page-width="8.1cm"
                               margin-top="1cm"
                               margin-bottom="1cm"
                               margin-left="1.5cm"
                               margin-right="1.5cm">
            <fo:region-body   margin-top="1cm"/>
           </fo:simple-page-master>
 <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest"
                               page-height="15.2cm"
                               page-width="8.1cm"
                               margin-top="1cm"
                               margin-bottom="1cm"
                               margin-left="1.5cm"
                               margin-right="1.5cm">
            <fo:region-body   margin-top="1cm"/>

           </fo:simple-page-master>
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="standard">
<fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-name="rest"/>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
</fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="standard"  force-page-count="no-force">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="8pt">
          <fo:block text-align="right" >
              <fo:page-number/> / <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="totalPages"/>
          </fo:block>
       <!--content-->
<fo:block id="totalPages"></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
          </fo:page-sequence>

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="rest"  force-page-count="no-force">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="8pt">
          <fo:block text-align="right" >
              <fo:page-number/> / <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="totalPages"/>
          </fo:block>
         <!--content-->
       <fo:block id="totalPages"></fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence> 
</fo:root>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.  What do you mean by 'multiple pages' when you also say that multiple pages work individually?  You could try looking at the samples at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/ to see if they help you.

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in the code shown so far, but the page-sequence doesn't contain any code that refers to your content. As-is, your code would generate two empty pages.